# How to remove the last svn revision?

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I want to remove  the last revision (or last n revisions) from a repository.

How to do it?

Is it possible to remove the svn revision files from `project/db/revs/` and from `project/db/revprops/` ?

Comment: You must not touch /db/revs/ and /db/revprops/ manually unless you have major reason and experience/knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check SVNBook: [**Repository Maintenance**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnadmin).

`svnadmin dump <path-to-repository> -r 0:99 > mydump.dump`

Where 99 is your N-1 number. This way you create a dump of your repository from 0 to 99 revision and can load into a new fresh repository with `svnadmin load`.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried to do exactly what you suggested in your question and it worked!

First, you remove the last revision from `db/revprops` and `db/revs`. Then you also have to decrement the numbers in `db/current` and `db/txn-current`

If any other developer already had checked out the last revision then they must check out again fresh. Having checked out an older revision seems to be ok.

There will be no unforseen sideeffects because I made a diff with before and after and the databases were identical (after commit & removing the last rev).

But I think it is very clear that you can only remove revisions at the end of the chain. Removing a revision from in the middle can screw up the deltas between the revisions.

**You dont need to be an expert in svn database structure to do such simple things, as bahrep suggested in the comments**

Comment: Worked fine for me, thanks a lot!  HOWEVER, I didn't decrease the (base 63) db/txn-current.  That seems not necessary, and not wise.  That is an increase-only number whose only role is to keep being incremented, so that it is never duplicated.

Comment: Note that I also deleted `db\rep-cache.db` to make sure that nothing was left accidentally from that incorrect commit.  From https://www.reddit.com/r/svn/comments/2hc9f1/repcachedb/cobfyu4/, that is a safe action to do: "Rep-cache is [...] an SQLite database that serves to allow SVN to do de-duplication. [...] If you delete the file nothing breaks with your repository, it just might end up being bigger than it would be otherwise."

Comment: You also need to delete records of your revision changes from the db\rep-cache.db file. If working under linux, open the SQLite file with "sqlite3 db\rep-cache.db" and remove hashes (i.e: revision 666), use the command "DELETE FROM rep_cache WHERE revision =666;"

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to remove the last revision? Does it contain data that may be sensitive in nature, and should never be seen by anyone, or was the last revision a real stinker?

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16945744/368630), you can do a dump and load via `svnadmin`. It takes your repository down and is usually more of a pain than it is worth. However, it does make it seem as that last revision never took place. It's the only way to completely rub out the revision. Something you might do only when information in that revision is something that's very proprietary or something that could get your company sued.

An easier way is to simply revert that bad revision. You can revert the last revision (or any revision) via the `svn merge` command:

```
$ svn merge -c -$rev_to_remove .
```

The old removed revision's history will still be there, and it will be accessible if a user knows Subversion well enough. But, the state of the repository will be back where it was before that last fatal revision.

Comment: In our case, we had a large 100,000+ commit repository which is the svnsync copy of our main repository.  Because of a configuration problem, accidentally a commit was done to that repository manually, breaking svnsync.  So I just needed to remove that single last revision, there simply is no other way.  Dump-load would have worked, but would have been way too expensive and invasive, and merging wouldn't solve the issue.  This is where [feedc0de](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1798015/feedc0de)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46560322/223837) really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, removing a revision involves creating a new copy of the repository with the particular revision removed.  If it's a small check-in, I'd say get the previous version, move those files to the side, get latest, then copy the previous files on top and check back in.

Comment: Comitted files will still be in the repository.

Comment: @bahrep - You are correct that committed files would still be in the repo.  It's a matter of whether you care.